# How to create azure virtual machine without a OS disk

Tags: azure

Is there anyway to create azure virtual machine without a OS disk through script or any command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, unless the target OS disk has been properly back-up with tools such as Azure Backup, which has an option to restore only OS disk, as per this example:

```
az backup restore restore-disks **--restore-only-osdisk**
```

However, I suspect your case is you wanting to simply "import" some kind of on-premises VM disk and hope the result to be fully functioning VM. If that is the case, you might want to try to create a new VM with an attach disk option, via PowerShell, as per instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/attach-os-disk?tabs=portal